# setup ttl based on PK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB has a feature to allow you setup ttl based on PK+SK, I'm wondering how it support ttl only based on PK.
Is it possible to setup a ttl that works on all entries of a PK?

I'm currently running some cron job on removing old data everyday.

It'll be sweet if dynamodb has such PK based ttl feature and not consuming capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any feature in DyanamoDb that allows you to expire items based on Hash/Range key(s) specifically.  The [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) feature for dynamo isn't based directly on the Hash and/or Range keys, you choose *any single* attribute that may be present on your items as the TTL attribute (it could be the Hash key, or the Range key, or any other non-key attribute that may exist on items in your table) - I say may exist because it isn't required that it exist on all items (any items that do not have the TTL attribute will simply be ignored, i.e. never expire).  You pick one (and only one - not multiple) attribute that Dynamo will then use to determine if items should be automatically expired, and when they do so, they are deleted automatically (just as if you had submitted a DeleteItem call yourself).  Note that the auto-cleanup itself isn't immediate, it can take up to 48 hours for expired items to actually be deleted.

The TTL attribute you select must simply be in epoch time format (i.e. a standard Unix Timestamp), so in your case, if your existing HashKey is a timestamp, you simply use that as your TTL attribute.  I imagine that is not the case, so your best option would likely be to add a timestamp attribute that defines the creation time of the item in standard unix-timestamp format and then configuring your table with that attribute as the TTL attribute.

More info on the TTL feature, how to configure it, etc. can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think what I'm going for is that I want to auto delete everything related to a PK with only setting ttl once. Looks like currently I have to set ttl attribute for every entry the PK has.